# Search table content based on title attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have search button to my tables.The search button should filter the values based on title tag value in first and second cell of row and also with whole row.I am able to do this without depending on title tag but I need to do this with title tag also.

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable Table</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." autocomplete="off">
  <br>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Testname</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Created on</th>
        <th>Updated on</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td title="test_name">Test Name</td>
        <td title="test desctiption"> trail testing</td>
        <td>yesterday</td>
        <td>two hour ago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td title="test_name">
          Trail Test
        </td>
        <td title="desctiption">testing</td>
        <td>today</td>
        <td>a hour ago</td>>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and removed the PHP tag. PHP has no influence on the question. Please update the HTML with relevant RENDERED HTML  to show the issue

Comment: PS: Typo: `desctiption`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the title text too:
(PS: Do not toggle in the filter - that is abusing a side-effect)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var re = RegExp(value.replace(/([\(\)])/g,"\\$1"), "i"); // escape ()
    $("#myTable tr").hide().filter(function() {
      var inTitle = $(this).find("td").filter(function() {
        return re.test(this.title);
      }).length > 0; // is in title?

      return re.test($(this).text()) || inTitle
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable Table</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." autocomplete="off">
  <br>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Testname</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Created on</th>
        <th>Updated on</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td title="test1">Test Name</td>
        <td title="( test1d )"> trail testing</td>
        <td>yesterday</td>
        <td>one hour ago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td title="test2">
          Trail Test
        </td>
        <td title="(test2d)">testing</td>
        <td>today</td>
        <td>a hour ago</td>>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But, it test_name contains () it is not searching.(Like test(1)_copy or test[1])

Comment: PS: That was not part of your original specification nor found in any title in your example.

Comment: Thank you  sir :)